# Neo4j Plugin Recursive

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-plugin

I'm trying to create my own function for neo4j that recursively goes through a graph and returns any nodes and edges that are connected to an edge with a long value greater than 100.

I know there is a simple CYPHER query for it but by doing this, I can know how to proceed with more complex stuff on my own.

**pseudocode**

1. get all relations from node matching Id where the relationship is type 'TypeExample'.
2. if the relation has a long property "Count" and Count > 100, go to 1.
3. IF 5 nodes deep, stop. return list of nodes and edges with interface IPath.

   ```
   package example;

   import java.util.Iterator;
   import java.util.stream.Stream;
   import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;
   import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
   import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
   import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
   import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
   import org.neo4j.graphdb.ResourceIterator;
   import org.neo4j.logging.Log;
   import org.neo4j.procedure.*;
   import org.neo4j.procedure.Description;
   import org.neo4j.procedure.Name;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Map;
   import java.util.Set;
   import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.Index;
   import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.IndexManager;

   public class NodeFinder {

   @Context
   public GraphDatabaseService db;

   @Context
   public Log log;

   @Procedure
   @Description("finds Nodes one step away")
   public Stream<SomeList> GetRelations(@Name("nodeId") long nodeId, @Name("depth") long depth, @Name("rel") String relType) {
       Recursive(nodeId);
      //return list of Nodes and Edges 
   }

   private void Recursive(long id) {
       Node node = db.getNodeById(nodeId);
       Iterable<Relationship> rels = node.getRelationships();

       for (Relationship rel : rels) {
           long c = (long) rel.getProperty("Count");
           if (c > 100) {
               Recursive(rel.getEndNodeId());
           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to view the source code for those?

Comment: I think your comment above was meant for @GuyCoder's answer, and does not belong under your own question.

Comment: I think he may have deleted his comment.